# asp.net mvc Html.Listbox - how to add an item manually

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am looking for a way to manually add items to html.ListBox in mvc. I want the top item to be "All Items".
i.e.

```
All Items
Item1
Item2
Item3
```

I am currently calling:

```
<%=Html.ListBox("items", Model.Items, new { style = "height:50px;width:100%" })%>
```

I may have to add it in the model when setting up the MultiSelectList, but would be prefer to add this in the controller.

Cheers

Comment: Can you post some of the controller's code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply have your view model contain a list of SelectListItem and add the item manually in the controller. For example:

```
List<SelectListItem> modelSelectList = model.Select(x => new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = x.Name,
                    Value = x.ID.ToString()
                }).ToList();

modelSelectList .Add(new SelectListItem() { Selected = false, Text = "All Items", Value = "-1");
```

Comment: thanks for the reply Dan. Will work but need to position the item at the top of the list

Comment: Sorted - converted to IList<SelectListItem> and then did and Insert at 0. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer doing it in your controller, but for a quick fix I guess you could do something like

```
<% var items = Model.Items.ToList(); items.Insert(0, new SelectListItem() { Text = "All items" }); %>
<% Html.ListBox("items", items, new { style = "height:50px;width:100%" })%>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rune. How would you get the correct ordinance at the controller. Simply Adding will only append to the bottom of the bound items?

Comment: Sorted - converted to IList<SelectListItem> and then did and Insert at 0.

Thanks